# What is a work-appropriate "small" object for a joke?

Tags: offensive-language, jokes, humor, business-language

Trying to think of a way to make this joke work-appropriate.

"**If we store GPS coordinates to a precision of 10 decimal points, we could even measure the size of your *[expletive deleted]*.**"

What is something funnily small, yet work appropriate?

I've tried a few, but doesn't have the same impact:

- my pension
- your remaining hairline
- my post-divorce bank account
- quarks

Comment: What's the nature of the business?

Comment: software company

Comment: Unless you really insist on attacking one individual (yourself included), I’d change the “your/my” to “our” and have the joke attack the company instead.  This might open up more possibilities (& for me, it makes “our pensions” [or even something like “our parking (G?) spots”] pretty funny, or at least less aggressive against co-workers).

Comment: I would avoid anything with "your" as having the potential to offend, and would avoid anything related to compensation/benefits ("my pension") assuming not everyone has the same (maybe you joke that your pension is small, but someone else doesn't have any pension at all).  Consider a space with a small physical area -- e.g., if the office has a small microwave and that is well-known -- or something to do with small creatures (a mouse's smartwatch?), or just go with "quarks" which is perfectly safe.   Sometimes jokes you can make at work without worrying are not the funniest jokes!

Comment: Thanks - these are good tips. I do like the size of parking spots / kitchen as a reference. I think I will play it safe and stay topical with "Trump's hairline" or "the education budget" or something (Trump comment is probably safe here because we live in the bluest of blue states, and his only value to us is entertainment value anyway.)

Comment: One last thought: As long as you go with “our” (and not ‘your’ or ‘my’) you **might** get away with using a suggestive piece of **gender-neutral** clothing that is designed to be small, e.g., “our briefs” (too bad you’re not a law firm); “our boxers” (too bad you’re not a sports-agency firm); or even “our thongs”(too bad  I suggested that, ‘cause it’s a bad idea [unless you do branch out and start representing some Sumo wrestlers!]).

Comment: I've got to point out that even if you were to store to 10 decimal places, GPS is not capable of resolving to 10 decimal places. (And of course if you need 10 decimal places to resolve the size of your **** I'm sorry. ;-))

Comment: Yeah that was the whole joke. I was arguing that 6 was plenty (decimeter precision) but somebody wanted 10 (~11 nanometer precision) and so I was trying to hammer the point home by insulting his genitalia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... even measure **who got there first**†

†if the GPS device were small enough not to have an adverse effect upon motility.

Comment: Ok, still trying to get this, so thought I'd ask - huh?? Is it a reference to a photo finish or something? Did you really mean `motility` or is that a typo? So confused..

Comment: No, not a typo :)

Comment: I am guessing this refers to sperm cells, the difference between the one that *did* get there first and the runners-up being measured in units much smaller than a millimeter. "Motility" is a measure of sperm cells' ability to reach its goal.

Answer (score -1):

I would vote for *IQ* - ([Intelligence Quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient)).  Basically it implies that the butt of the joke is somewhat below par on intelligence.